# Report GLM and Posthoc with emmeans in APA format

Tags: r, regression, logistic, post-hoc, reporting

This is the results of my `anova(glm())` and the post-hoc analyses `emmeans()` :

```
         Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                                 515     1336.6              
Type_product        3   32.544       512     1304.0 4.019e-07 ***
Exhaustion_product  9   92.167       503     1211.8 5.977e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1[/code]

gl=glm(Effort ~  Type_product +  Exhaustion_product, family=poisson , data=vect)
library("emmeans")
emmp <- emmeans( gl, pairwise ~ Type_product)
summary( emmp, infer=TRUE)

 contrast    estimate         SE  df    asymp.LCL   asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 c - f    -0.14084934 0.04221684 Inf -0.249305743 -0.03239295  -3.336  0.0047
 c - m     0.33882907 0.08050197 Inf  0.132016967  0.54564118   4.209  0.0002
 c - s     0.31167356 0.12274400 Inf -0.003659682  0.62700680   2.539  0.0541
 f - m     0.47967842 0.08339482 Inf  0.265434484  0.69392235   5.752  <.0001
 f - s     0.45252290 0.12076017 Inf  0.142286189  0.76275962   3.747  0.0010
 m - s    -0.02715551 0.14317625 Inf -0.394979861  0.34066883  -0.190  0.9976
```

There is significant effect of `Effort` and `Type_product`  (χ2(3)=32.5, p<0.001). Post-hoc test report decreasing `Effort` of `C` comparing to `F`.

Firstly, I want to be sure that my GLM reporting is correct.

After that, I can't found any APA format reporting for post-hoc test (p-value, estimate?)

How to report these values ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in your paper you should show a table of the EMMs and SEs, and another table showing the comparisons among them and their Tukey-adjusted P values. Possibly you should do them with `type = “response"` so that the results are on a more interpretable scale. A graph or two might help as well.

In submitting a paper to a journal, your responsibility is to show the reviewers as clearly as possible what you did and how you justify your findings. If the journal wants the results expressed more succinctly to save pages, that’s understandable, and can be accomplished later. It should not come at the expense of the reviewers and editors’ clear understanding of the methods and procedures being used.